# python mutable default параметры

Tags: python, python-faq

У меня вопрос по теме [дефолтных параметров у функций](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/). 
То есть по

```
>>> def foo(my_list=[]):
...   my_list.append(1)
...   return my_list
... 
>>> foo()
[1]
>>> foo()
[1, 1]
>>> foo()
[1, 1, 1]
>>>
```

Я понимаю почему так происходит (вопрос разумности такого поведения оставим за рамками)

Правильно ли я понимаю, что если **единожды** вызвать функцию с таким вот дефолтным списком, где заполнить его гигабайтом данных, вернуть, использовать и потом забыть, то память все равно будет удерживаться за счет того, что дефолтный [] приколочен к def foo?

Comment: Если рассматривать функцию как объект, то по идее сборщик мусора может убрать и саму функцию, и связанную с ней память (например, в дефолтных параметрах) после последнего использования функции. Как оно по факту - не могу сказать.

Comment: @insolor в обычных условиях когда функция просто функция или как метод класса невозможно сказать когда будет "последнее использование". Даже если это метод класса и создать новый объект, то он продолжает шарить все ту же дефолтную переменную привязанную к методу. То есть я не вижу никаких вариантов, кроме как не использовать дефолтные мутабельные параметры вовсе ибо они грозят утечкой памяти даже при однократном вызове

Comment: Сейчас попробовал, похоже, действительно память сама не возвращается. Память освобождается только если явно вызвать `del foo`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev дубликат. только мало быть дубликатом - еще нужно чтобы поиском легко находилось, а с этим у дубликата большая проблема

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дефолтный аргумент создается один раз, в месте определения функции foo и хранится в ней же, это просто обычная переменная, к которой вы можете получить доступ не вызывая foo()

Eсли бы вы создали неизменяемый аргумент по умолчанию, размером в гигабайт, он ведь не должен обнулятся при перевызове foo, в этом его смысл, хранить теже данные. Так почему же my_list должен освобождатся?

Разница изменяемый это аргумент или нет, в том что при вызове foo будет создаватся новый(если неизменяемый, например tupple) my_list или обновлен тотже(если изменяемый) my_list

обнулить можно удалив объект foo в котором и хранится my_list
или обнулив сам my_list

```
def foo(my_list=[]):
    my_list.append(list(range(10)))
    return my_list

print(foo.__defaults__)
foo()

print(foo.__defaults__)

foo.__defaults__[0].clear()

print(foo.__defaults__)

([],)
([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],)
([],)
```

Comment: >в этом его смысл, хранить теже данные. Так почему же my_list должен освобождатся?
...Потому что это ожидаемое поведение  - создать значение, если оно не передано. И все!. И уж никак не создавать общую "статическую" переменную. Переданные переменные *локальны* внутри функции и созданные неявно должны быть точно такие же - ведь цель дефолтности является "необязательность параметра". Я понимаю причины - сделали реализацию попроще и с целью оптимизаций скорости работы, но это не есть ожидаемо (и собственно в других языках такой бяки нет), а просто "особенность" конкретно питона.

Comment: вам нужно прочитать чем отличаются mutable от immutable, но в общет да

Comment: я знаю чем они отличаются, потому это и было неожиданностью для меня в питоне (с учетом философии питона), что оказывается питон по своему решает проблему необязательных аргументов (вернее плохо решает, потому что для мутабельных приходится устанавливать =None и потом все равно вручную создавать) и вместо синтаксического сахара заботливо разложил грабли о которых нужно помнить.

Comment: мне кажется в питоне такой подход везде, ведь даже foo или print  или clear являются объектами классов, которые наследуются от type. Те создаются один раз, подобно дефолтным аргументам

Comment: @vitidev: данные не статические: у каждой функции свои данные как у всех других объектов в Питоне. Если вы понимаете, что функция это объект и значения по умолчанию вычисляются в момент создания функции, тогда поведение становится очевидным. Вас же не удивляет, что `d = dict(a=[])` конструкция не приводит к созданию новых списков при каждом обращении: `d['a']`? (список создаётся, когда словарь создаётся.`d['a']` всегда на один и тот же список ссылается, пока явно не заменить).

Comment: @jfs 2 года прошло. Я понимаю механизм. не одобряю конечно, потому что он следствие реализации питона, а не ожиданий программиста (как в любом другом языке) но понимаю. А в d = dict(a=[]) не удивляет, потому что тут именно такого и ожидаешь.

Comment: @vitidev: да хоть бы и 100 лет прошло, пока Питон используется, неверные утверждения и заблуждения стоит поправлять¶ Про ожидания: ваша логика напоминает логику человека, который Windows всю жизнь использовал и придя на Unix говорит что всё не так и плохо, если способ работы не совпадает с Windows.

Comment: @jfs мои ожидания из синтаксиса: "если я не передал параметр, то пусть этот параметр будет ПУСТЫМ списком". Это ожидания из синтаксиса, а не потому что во всех других языках так. А то, что этот список не пустой может быть - подводный камень самого питона, но не логики