# Переменные функции Python живут между вызовами функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть функция в Python:

```
def to_list(val, default_list=[]):
    default_list.append(val)
    return default_list
```

Я немного сбит с толку, потому что

```
print(to_list('a'))
print(to_list('v'))
```

Возвращают соответственно:

```
['a']
['a', 'v']
```

Почему список `default_list` доступен с содержимым сохранённым из предыдущего вызова (содержит `'a'`)? Ведь область видимости функции очищается после её выполнения. А `default_list` часть этой области видимости и должен был быть очищен после первого вызова. Нет? Почему он сохранился?

Благодарю.

Comment: [Необычное поведение области видимости: изменяемый аргумент по умолчанию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/698455)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что список - это очень коварная вещь в питоне и с ним надо быть акуратнее.

Вот так будет работать так, как задумали:

```
def to_list(val, default_list=None):
    if default_list is None:
        default_list = []
        default_list.append(val)
    return default_list

print(to_list('a'))
print(to_list('v'))
```

Напечатает:

```
['a']
['v']
```

В описании функции нельзя объявлять список так:

```
def to_list(val, default_list=[]):
```

т.к. у вас сохранится ссылка на список и при каждом вызове этой функции - Вы будете не создавать новый список, а лишь подключаться к существующей ссылке. Подробнее можете почитать там:

> [Создание списка](https://pythonchik.ru/osnovy/spiski-v-python#:%7E:text=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%91%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%2C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%2C%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%203%2D%D1%85%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%3A)

Comment: "Очень коварная вещь" - это не ответ. Ответ мог бы быть "потому что аргументы по умолчанию инициализируются только один раз - в тот момент, когда интерпретатор обрабатывает определение функции, а не при каждом вызове функции, как в других языках".

Comment: @CrazyElf, я позже в конце добавил почему

Comment: "Вот так будет работать так, как задумали" – с чего вы взяли что я так задумывал? Но согласен, так более очевидно. Однако всё-равно спасибо! Тоже хорошо объясняется тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/698455/Необычное-поведение-области-видимости-изменяемый-аргумент-по-умолчанию https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559310/python-mutable-default-параметры https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument